# Specifying y-array and plot label in Pandas DataFrame plot changes the dataframe's index label/name?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with index label named as 'RowNumber'.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(5,3), index=np.arange(5), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df.index.name='RowNumber'
df

Out[1]: 
                  A         B         C
RowNumber                              
0          0.994063  0.068659  0.158425
1          0.116639  0.109248  0.160374
2          0.086689  0.269934  0.060204
3          0.794417  0.988650  0.306970
4          0.193915  0.230677  0.414131
```

I plot a errorbar plot, with legend.

```
df.plot(y='B', yerr='C', label='Test')
plt.legend(loc=0)
```

[image]

But this changes the label/name of index_column to 'Test'.

```
             A         B         C
Test                              
0     0.994063  0.068659  0.158425
1     0.116639  0.109248  0.160374
2     0.086689  0.269934  0.060204
3     0.794417  0.988650  0.306970
4     0.193915  0.230677  0.414131
```

Why ? I want to plot a dataframe, not change it. 
This happens even with the simple line plot, not only errorplot, as long as one specify `y=...` and `label=...`.

Comment: I'm running IPython 2.2.0, Python 2.7.8 on OSX 10.9.2 .

Comment: the version of pandas that you are using is more relevant the version of Python, IPython, or even your operating system.

Comment: I'm using pandas 0.14.1 . Thanks Paul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the label parameter in the call to `df.plot` alters the DataFrame's index name ([source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tools/plotting.py#L2277)):

```
        label = kwds.pop('label', label)
        ser = frame[y]
        ser.index.name = label
```

You might want to raise this as [an issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/new), but given that this is the way the plot method works, you could instead set the label(s) in the call to `plt.legend`:

```
df.plot(y='B', yerr='C')
plt.legend( ('Test',), loc=0 )
plt.show()
```

[image]

This leaves `df.index.name` unchanged.

```
In [10]: df.index.name
Out[10]: 'RowNumber'
```

Comment: Thanks unutbu. I created [the issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8494) using your answer.